# I need an sql query that gives me a teacher who teach two specified subject

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.4

I have a database with teachers and students and i need to find out which teacher  teach subject A and subject B.

```
select nameteacher
from teacher inner join 
     university 
     on teacher.codt = university.codt inner join 
     subject 
     on university.coddisc = subject.coddisc
where subjects=('A') AND subjects=('B');
```

my version doesn't work what should i do ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  How do you even know if a teacher is teaching one particular  subject?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query that gives distinct results that match multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1202668/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want `group by` and `having`:

```
select t.teacher_name
from teacher t
inner join university u on t.codt = u.codt
inner join subject s on u.coddisc = s.coddisc
where s.subject_name in ('A', 'B')
group by t.teacher_id, t.teacher_name
having count(*) = 2
```

Depending on your actual dataset, you might need a more restrictive `having` clause:

```
having count(distinct s.subject_name) = 2
```