# MySQL Join query: Two main and one linking table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a Star Wars project that I am working on for Uni.

In my database, I have multiple tables and linking tables.  I'm trying to query

> "What mode of transport has been used by Rey, Obi-Wan Kenobi and
>   C-3PO?"

Answer (obviously) is Millennium Falcon.

I've set up the query using INNER JOINs but I'm stuck at the end.

```
SELECT t.type AS OnlyTransportItCouldBe 
FROM transport AS t
INNER JOIN person_transport AS pt
ON pt.transport_id = t.id
INNER JOIN person AS p
ON pt.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.name = 'Rey'
```

The above returns 3 ships, but I'm confuddled as to how also check Old Ben and Goldenrod.  I've tried `AND p.name = "Obi-Wan Kenobi"` and it returns blank.  If I try `WHERE p.name = 'Rey', 'Obi-Wan Kenobi'` it fails, if I try `WHERE p.name = 'Rey' AND 'Obi-Wan Kenobi'`, the result is blank.  I know it's something really simple, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: OK, so I've tried - OR WHERE p.name IN ('Rey', 'Obi-Wan Kenobi', 'C-3PO') - and it errored, so I tried - WHERE p.name IN ('Rey', 'Obi-Wan Kenobi', 'C-3PO') - and it returned all the ships they've been associated with.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1202668/3404097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to get the **common** modes of transport that have been used by *Rey*, *Obi-Wan Kenobi* and *C-3PO* then you must `group by type` and add a `having` clause like ethis:

```
SELECT t.type AS OnlyTransportItCouldBe 
FROM transport AS t
INNER JOIN person_transport AS pt ON pt.transport_id = t.id
INNER JOIN person AS p ON pt.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.name IN ('Rey', 'Obi-Wan Kenobi', 'C-3PO')
GROUP BY t.type
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.name) = 3
```

Comment: Hi forpas.  Not quite.  What I'm trying to do is show the only ship that they have all used.  I did try the code that you suggested, and it returned an empty result.  However, changing the DISTINCT from 3 to 2 worked.  Thanks buddy