# How can I select records that match multiple values in a linking table using a MySQL join statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to fix a query used for product filtering that works fine for a single category, but is very wrong when multiple categories are selected. The query is currently selecting all products whose id's match one cat_id OR another, which is a start, but I can't figure out how to only get the products whose id's match BOTH chosen cat_id's in categories_linked.

Here's an example of the query that is currently running when two filters are selected:

```
SELECT A.* FROM products A LEFT JOIN categories_linked B ON A.id = B.prod_id WHERE (B.cat_id = 1 || B.cat_id = 2) GROUP BY A.id;
```

For example, if I filtered by cat_id 1 and 2, I would want the product with id 1 returned, but currently it returns products with id's 1, 2 and 3. The WHERE clause is generated dynamically, so if it can be maintained, even better.

categories_linked

```
cat_id|prod_id|
------+-------+
     1|      1|
     1|      2|
     2|      1|
     2|      3|
```

products

```
id |title |
---+------+
  1| item1|   
  2| item2|  
  3| item3|
```

Comment: This isn't what you're asking about, but--Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a LEFT JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS || is now deprecated & per mode might mean CONCAT.

Comment: Please format your code reasonably. Please in code questions give a [mre]. But this is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS You can do what you want via literal list or a table. Which?

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
 [SQL query that gives distinct results that match multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1202668/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy I changed || to OR and no change. Your link to possible duplicate doesn't seem to apply. I'm not sure what you mean by "You can do what you want via literal list or table".

Comment: Please give a [mre], including example data. Re "list or table" see the answers--some use `in (list)` & some use `in (subquery)`. You need to join then use the answer in the link. Understand the linked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to /u/r3pr0b8 on Reddit for helping when not surprisingly, SO would not.

```
SELECT products.* 
  FROM ( SELECT prod_id
          FROM categories_linked  
          WHERE cat_id IN ( 1 , 2 )
         GROUP
             BY prod_id
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cat_id) = 2
       ) AS these       
INNER
  JOIN products
    ON products.id = these.prod_id
```